# What is the year of the Tour de France poster

Tags: cycling, history

In the movie [Triplets of Belleville](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286244/) there appears a Tour de France poster that is hanging near the Champion's bed (a picture from the movie that I found is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4HLG.jpg), the poster is the one with the blue-white-red map of France). Which Tour de France had that particular poster? Where can I find the image?

Comment: This seems to be more of a movie trivia question than a sports question...

Comment: BTW there also exists [movies.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286244/trivia):

> The yellow-jerseyed leader of the Tour de France depicted in the film
>   is a caricature of five-time tour winner Jacques Anquetil. It would
>   appear that the year is 1957, the year of Anquetil's first win and the
>   only year he participated which featured a stage finish in Marseilles.